# Modify native-base Input component to show InputRightElement only when focused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I want to use native-base input element to show the letter count on the right side when it's focused.

I'd like to be able to write the following but _focus only accepts some props

```
<Input
  flex="1"
  size="lg"
  placeholder="Choice 2"
  _focus={{
   bg: '',
   borderColor: theme.colors.surfaceBlue,
   InputRightElement: <Text mr="2">x25</Text>,
 }}
/>
```

Instead, it looks like I'll need to do the following:

```
          <Input
            flex="1"
            size="lg"
            placeholder="Choice 2"
            _focus={{
              bg: '',
              borderColor: theme.colors.surfaceBlue,
            }}
            InputRightElement={
              showRightElement ? <Text mr="2">x25</Text> : <></>
            }
            onFocus={() => setShowRightElement(true)}
          />
```

However, don't want to set up boolean state for each input. Is there an alternative way of showing right element when focused?